# how to limit a sql integer query result to <=1

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer

how to limit an integer query result to 1. a return of 2 to be 1, a return 1 to be 1, and a return of 0.5 to be 0.5 because it is <= 1. i don't want to modify the tables, i just want to modify the results.

This is my exact query.

```
select ((select "V01" from sports where "UID" = '1') * 1.0 ) / 
(select "V01" from master where "BALL" = 'REQUIREMENT') ;
```

I'm using postgres.

Comment: Just a quick note that you can't return 0.5 in an integer.  You'll need to be casting to something else like numeric to get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit, you'd do something like this:

```
select 
    case 
        when yourNumber >= 1 then 1
        else yourNumber
    end
...
```

Then you just apply this concept to your query.

As noted by Wiseguy, you could also do:

```
select LEAST(yourNumber, 1)
```

, since this is postgresql.

The first solution will work with any ANSI SQL compatible database.

**Update**

Applied to your query, I think (if I understood what you want correctly) it would be like this:

```
select LEAST(1,
               ((select "V01" from sports where "UID" = '1') * 1.0 ) / 
               (select "V01" from master where "BALL" = 'REQUIREMENT')
       );
```

Comment: How about `LEAST(number, 1)`?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I saw that. But it's kind of pointless though, don't you think?

Comment: @Adrian: Yes. I am sorry, I get it now. Edited.

Comment: Thanks LEAST did it and thank you for giving me the exact syntax!

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer the helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

use the `LEAST` function , docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-conditional.html. Also, check out `GREATEST` too

```
SELECT LEAST(1, <your value>)
```

**EDIT** replaced GREATEST with LEAST

Comment: I really think you mean LEAST

Comment: yeah, I probably meant LEAST :). Thanks. I was quick and lazy.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select CASE 
         WHEN ((select V01 from sports where UID = '1') * 1.0 ) / 
               (select V01 from master where BALL = 'REQUIREMENT') >= 1
         THEN 1
         ELSE ((select V01 from sports where UID = '1') * 1.0 ) / 
               (select V01 from master where BALL = 'REQUIREMENT')
       END;
```